# Insert key value to HashTable when value is an ArrayList

Tags: java, hashtable

I am running a for loop over some string values and I want to update the Arraylist value (for a particular key) in the pass of the loop only but when I search how to put arraylist values for a key,I can find the solution where the value is updated after all the values of the arraylist is updated.
Suppose for key sub I want to enter the string as soon as i get value val

```
                data.put(sub,new ArrayList<String>(val));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to add elements to the Arraylist (value) one by one
>   rather than one time with put.

One can't add anything to the `ArrayList` by `put(...)`, but by `add()`

If you want to add value one by one to the `ArrayList` you may use foreach loop:

```
for(TypeOfTheSingleElementFromTheSet variable: setOfElementsWhichImplementsIterable){
    list.add(variable);
}
```

---

**After rephrasing the original post**

```
data.get(sub).add(val); //where data is reference to an object which implements Map interface
```

Comment: the put is for Hashtable which contains <string Arraylist<string>>

Comment: @aditirana Read about duck typing in Java, HashTable is a Map. HashTable -> All Implemented Interfaces:  Serializable, Cloneable, Map<K,V>

Comment: but this can work when the key is already present.I have to check data.containsKey(sub).For that case it is right but for the first entry of a key I have to add empty Arraylist.But I am unable to do so